# How to count the times a particular item appears in a query output

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a query with a lot of tables and joins. So a simple Count(column) and Group By isn't working correctly.
The query returns an item list. I want to calculate how many times each item appears in that list.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT DECODE(BOM.ORGANIZATION_ID,203, 'CEC', 328, '3PL', 204, 'SIM') ORGANIZATION_CODE,
  BOM.ORGANIZATION_ID,
  MSI.SEGMENT1 "PARENT_ITEM",
  MSIC.SEGMENT1 "COMPONENT_ITEM",
  SUM(NVL(MMT.TRANSACTION_QUANTITY,0)) * NVL(SUM(CIC.ITEM_COST),0) "ANNUAL_MONEY",
  SUM(NVL(MMT.TRANSACTION_QUANTITY,0)) "ANNUAL_QTY_USG",
  NVL(SUM(CIC.ITEM_COST),0) "AVG_COST",
  SUM(NVL(MSI.POSTPROCESSING_LEAD_TIME,0) + NVL(MSI.PREPROCESSING_LEAD_TIME,0)) LEAD_TIME
FROM BOM_BILL_OF_MATERIALS BOM
LEFT JOIN MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS MSI
ON MSI.ORGANIZATION_ID    = BOM.ORGANIZATION_ID
AND MSI.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = BOM.ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID
AND MSI.ENABLED_FLAG      = 'Y'
AND MSI.BOM_ENABLED_FLAG  = 'Y'
LEFT JOIN CST_ITEM_COSTS CIC
ON CIC.ORGANIZATION_ID    = BOM.ORGANIZATION_ID
AND CIC.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = BOM.ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID
AND CIC.COST_TYPE_ID      = 1
LEFT JOIN MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS MMT
ON MMT.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID     = BOM.ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID
AND MMT.ORGANIZATION_ID      = BOM.ORGANIZATION_ID
AND MMT.TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID IN (33,34,17)
LEFT JOIN MTL_TRANSACTION_TYPES MTT
ON MTT.TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID = MTT.TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID
LEFT JOIN BOM_INVENTORY_COMPONENTS BIC
ON BIC.BILL_SEQUENCE_ID = BOM.COMMON_BILL_SEQUENCE_ID
AND NVL(bic.disable_date, sysdate+1) > sysdate
LEFT JOIN BOM_COMPONENTS_B BCB
ON BIC.COMPONENT_SEQUENCE_ID = BCB.COMPONENT_SEQUENCE_ID
LEFT JOIN BOM_STRUCTURES_B BSB
ON BCB.BILL_SEQUENCE_ID = BSB.BILL_SEQUENCE_ID
LEFT JOIN MFG_LOOKUPS ML
ON ML.LOOKUP_CODE  = BIC.WIP_SUPPLY_TYPE
AND ML.LOOKUP_CODE = BIC.ENFORCE_INT_REQUIREMENTS
AND ML.LOOKUP_TYPE = 'MTL_EAM_ITEM_TYPE'
LEFT JOIN MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS MSIC
ON MSIC.ORGANIZATION_ID    = BOM.ORGANIZATION_ID
AND MSIC.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = BIC.COMPONENT_ITEM_ID
LEFT JOIN BOM_OPERATIONAL_ROUTINGS BOR
ON BOR.ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID   = BOM.ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID
AND BOR.ORGANIZATION_ID   = BOM.ORGANIZATION_ID
WHERE BOM.ORGANIZATION_ID = NVL(:P_ORG_ID,BOM.ORGANIZATION_ID)
AND EXISTS
  (SELECT 'X'
  FROM MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS MMT
  WHERE MMT.TRANSACTION_DATE >= ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE,-12)
  AND MSI.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID IS NOT NULL
  )
GROUP BY BOM.ORGANIZATION_ID,
  MSI.SEGMENT1,
  MSIC.SEGMENT1
ORDER BY ORGANIZATION_CODE,
  MSIC.SEGMENT1
```

My output is like this now: [image]

I want to have another column which counts each item occurence in the output.

Comment: Please post your query and table structures.

Comment: Just take that query and make it a derived innards of a wrapping query

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Is it oracle or mysql?

Comment: @Aleksej Its in Oracle

Answer (score 1):

That's called conditional aggregation and you can do it with `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
SELECT <col1>,<col2>..,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN column ='Specific Val' THEN 1 END) as cnt
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY  <col1>,<col2>..,
```

In MySQL this is also fine:

```
SUM(column = 'Specific Val')
```

Because expressions are treated as 1 and 0 .

Comment: But I don't have a single table. The YourTable isn't a single table. As I said, my query has a lot of tables and their joins.

Comment: Why does that make a difference? It should still work.

Comment: OK, did you really expect me to guess your DB design ?  I'm not here to do your job, you're the one getting paid not me. That's the way to go, it can be done with 1 table, 5 or a 100 . @SoumyadeepPaul

Comment: I apologize if I said something wrong. I just didn't understand your answer fully. I'll try again and post back.

Comment: Either post your query, or just try to add it your self. The only thing you need to add to your query is instead of `COUNT(*)` , the `COUNT(CASE..)` . All the rest doesn't matter.

Comment: My search isn't item specific. I want to count the times each item appears in that output

Comment: @SoumyadeepPaul Please enter here > http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Add data sample, expected output and your current query. Without that, it's impossible to understand what you want.

Comment: I have now added some extra information to help others.

Comment: Try `COUNT(DISTINCT <Column>)` while the <Column> is some column that you want to count by it. @SoumyadeepPaul

Comment: Ok, I did that but the values of the Count column is not what I see from the query output. It returns 1 for every record.  It should ideally be 203 | 9010294 | 3, and so on.

Comment: I have also tried using this :count(CASE WHEN MSIC.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID=BIC.COMPONENT_ITEM_ID THEN 1 END) AS CNT, but for some reason, it returns all values as either 83 or multiples of 83 when the item appears more than one, which is wrong.
Using a DISTINCT with this count results in 1 for every record. What exactly am I doing wrong here?
I have also tried using the CASE statement in the GROUP BY, but with the same results. I have also removed the GROUP BY MSI.SEGMENT1 (ie. the Parent Item column) to group all the COMPONENT_ITEMs together.

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't **count(distinct column)** work here since you're already using a group by

Comment: On the contrary, `COUNT(distinct column)` will count the specific value only once.

Comment: That is exactly what it's doing

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
select count(*) from
(your query)
where column='value to be checked'
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT ColumnName, COUNT(*) 
FROM TableName 
GROUP BY ColumnName;
```

On the location of `TableName` you can also use a `(SELECT ....)`.